# Confused about how to properly JOIN

Tags: mysql

I have the following tables:

- log - stores info about each interaction.  Indexes on clickID (unique) and businessID (not unique).
- actions - stores info about each specific action taken by a customer. indexes on clickID, actionID, personID, businessID
- customers - stores info about each specific customer of a specific business. indexes on personID and businessID (neither is unique, but the combo of the two together will be)
- people - stores universal stats about each person who is a customer of one or more businesses.  Index on personID (unique).

I need to get all of this info in one result set to pull data from, so that I can connect interactions to individual people's data, and their business-specific data.

I am currently using two datasets, that I correlate in PHP, but I'd prefer to work from one returned dataset, if it makes sense.

Here is my current set of queries:

```
SELECT * FROM `log`
WHERE `timestamp` >= STARTTIME AND `timestamp` <= ENDTIME AND `pageID`='aPageID' AND `businessID`='aBusinessID'
ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC

SELECT * FROM `actions` AS `t1`
INNER JOIN `people` AS `t2` ON (`t1.personID`=`t2.personID`)
INNER JOIN `customers` AS `t2` ON (`t1.personID`=`t3.personID` AND `t1.businessID`=`t3.businessID`)
WHERE `timestamp` >= STARTTIME AND `timestamp` <= ENDTIME AND `pageID`='aPageID' AND `businessID`='aBusinessID'
ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC
```

It seems like I'd to better with one query where the actionID (and all following results) might be null, but I don't really know what that would look like, or how it would impact performance.  Help?

Comment: aren't you missing a businesses table there? What is businessID pointing to?

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier there is a business table, but it doesn't relate to this query, all that's important for this query is that it is all with regards to a single business that owns a page.  we know both of these values coming in to this query.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `log` AS t1
INNER JOIN `actions` AS t2 ON (t1.`clickID`=t2.`clickID` AND t1.`businessID`=t2.`businessID`)
INNER JOIN `customers` AS t3 ON (t1.`businessID`=t3.`BusinessID` AND t2.`personID`=t3.`personID`)
INNER JOIN `people` AS t4 ON (t2.`personID`=t4.`personID`)
WHERE `timestamp` >= STARTTIME AND `timestamp` <= ENDTIME AND `pageID`='aPageID' AND `businessID`='aBusinessID'
ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC
```

Comment: I'm a little confused by this.  each person can have lots of matching customer rows and lots of actions but there is only one set that should match the query in this case.  All of the relevant data to the WHERE statement is in the logs table, so shouldn't I start from there, being the most specific table to the query?

Comment: can you post a sample of desired result?

Comment: I have a huge number of columns that will make this very difficult to mock up, but essentially, I want all matching records from `log`. Where there are entries in `actions` that match the clickID in `log`, I want the matching columns from `actions` to be appended, otherwise, I want those columns to be null.  where there is an entry in `people` where the personID matches the personID in `actions`, I want those columns appended, otherwise null.  Where there is an entry in `customers` where the personID and userID match the personID and userID in `actions`, I want to add those columns.

Comment: also, for every entry in `actions` links to one record in `people`  by personID (but not vice-versa).  Every entry in `customers` links to one entry in people by personID, too.  Every entry in `actions` links to one record in `customers`, by a combination of personID and userID.

Comment: edited to fit your comment, if it still is not the thing, you will have to post table structure and desired data, even if very complicated, I won't shy away from them :) at the very least, your table structure as exported by phpmyadmin would help

Comment: the issue I see is that this edited query only gives me the log rows that contain actions.  Many log rows constitute bounces, where no action occurred.  I need to have these columns as well, (with nulls where the other table's fields would go)... this seems like a job for `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, but I know that can significantly effect speed of query.